# How to access a Drive file from addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have developed a Sheets editor addon that uses the SpreadsheetApp to create a new spreadsheet that will contain a subset of data in the current spreadsheet. The problem is that SpreadsheetApp creates the file in the users root directory, and I would like to move it to same directory as the parent spreadsheet.

This was possible and worked during development, but now that I am trying to publish it, it is failing due to the Drive oauth scope being "restricted" now (despite the fact that it is currently published "internal" only, which the docs state should bypass this restriction, even though it is not [unless I am misunderstanding or misconfiguring something]).

Is there any way to achieve this without having to use a restricted scope? The Drive API contains a drive.file scope that allows access to files created using the current app, but the built in DriveApp does not.

Comment: To follow up, it looks like I AM able to access a file created by the the script - I just cannot get the DriveApp file object for the current spreadsheet running the script...

Comment: Why do you want to use the DriveApp instead of Drive API if both can be used in Apps Script and both can be used to move a file?

Comment: DriveApp seems to be the built in solution for apps script dealing with drive items. It handles the other things that I need it to do, so I feel like using the Drive API as well is overkill to mix APIs for the same service.

I do actually believe that my ability to move the file is working - it appears the actual issue has been with checking .isTrashed() - getting a generic error about an issue with the drive service and to try again later, which others have indicated an issue with oauth scope permissions.

Comment: I am glad you solved the problem!